# Custom python widgets in glade 3

Tags: python, glade, pygobject

I would like to subclass an existing Gtk widget and get it to work with Glade3.  The code is all python, and I'm using PyGObject.

What I want to do is extend Gtk.TextView and be able to add it to my glade UI as if it were a native widget.

I read that it was possible with Glade 2, but I'm not sure how to do this with Glade 3, and I can't seem to find any examples or documentation on this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? I'm not exactly sure if this is what you mean...but if you want to create a widget in Glade without putting inside of a toplevel Gtk.Window, you can do this by right-clicking on a widget(let's say a Gtk.Box) in the panel on the side and select 'Add as toplevel'. This will allow you to create a *custom widget*. Hope that helps

Comment: See also: [Custom PyGTK Widgets in Glade3](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/custom-widgets-glade/Custom_PyGTK_Widgets_in_Glade3-part-2.html), [python - How to add a pygtk Widget to the Glade palette? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30496/how-to-add-a-pygtk-widget-to-the-glade-palette)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found out how to do it. First, you have to declare that your glade file depends upon a **catalog**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <!-- interface-requires the_catalog_name 1.0 -->
  ...Rest of the glade file...
```

Next, create a catalog.xml file.  To extend a treeview, it should look something like this:

```
<glade-catalog name="the_catalog_name" domain="glade-3" 
               depends="gtk+" version="1.0">
  <glade-widget-classes>
    <glade-widget-class title="My Custom Text View" name="CustomTextView" 
                        generic-name="CustomTextView" parent="GtkTextView"
                        icon-name="widget-gtk-textview"/>
  </glade-widget-classes>
</glade-catalog>
```

And that's it.  Obviously There's no python code written yet, but that won't prevent Glade from displaying your custom widget.  It will just treat it as a normal TextView, Label, or whatever else you want to extend.

Oh, and I couldn't find a way in Glade itself to create a CustomTextView unfortunately.  But what you can do is add a regular TextView in glade, save the glade file and open it in a text editor.  Just look for the treeview you created and change like so:

```
-              <object class="TreeView" id="treeview1">
+              <object class="CustomTreeView" id="treeview1">
```

Open it back up in glade and it shows up.  Then just define a CustomTreeView class in python and extend as needed.

Comment: Where does the catalog file belong, or how does the python script indicate where to look for it? (I hope it doesn't need to be installed in a system directory.)